# Where are the secret holiday gifts needed for the Winter Secrets achievement?

Tags: steam, achievements, trine

Recently, Trine was updated with a new achievement that involves finding Christmas gifts:

> Find the Academic, Bony and Crystalline holiday secret gifts.

The description seems to be a hint to the levels they appear in. Makes me think Academy Hallways, Crypt of the Damned and Crystal Caves.

Where exactly are those presents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mostly right. The levels where the gifts are located are Academy Hallways, Crystal Caves, and Dragon Graveyard. This video shows their exact locations:

Comment: Well, I wasn't completely right, then. I guessed Crypt of the Damned, but it was Dragon Graveyard.

Comment: I didn't even notice that. I can edit the answer to reflect that.